# Network share folder from Ubuntu 20.04 no longer appears in Windows 10 file explorer

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

So a few days ago I successfully set up Samba on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop and was able to access my shared network folder from my Windows 10 desktop in file explorer.

However, at one point I had to reboot my laptop due to internet issues, which then created another issue of not being able to access the shared network folder when clicking on it in the Windows file explorer. I tried doing research to figure out how to fix this, and one of the methods I found suggested to remove the credentials of the SMB server in Windows, then try connecting to it again:
[image]

Unfortunately after trying this, I made the issue worse as the shared folder doesn't even show up in the file explorer anymore when typing in the IP address of my laptop in the address bar. To add insult to injury, I soon later discovered the initial problem was actually due to the `smb.conf` file in Ubuntu somehow being reset to default after rebooting which caused the network folder path that I set up to be removed (which explains why I wasn't able to access the folder before when clicking on it in Windows).

After setting the configuration back to the way I had it, resetting Samba and making sure it's running properly, the network folder still will not show up in the Windows file explorer no matter what I do.

I tried adding back in the credentials on Windows with the IP address and user name of my Ubuntu laptop, nothing.

I tried changing these Windows features settings accordingly as many have suggested:

[image]

nothing.

I tried installing `wsdd` on my Ubuntu laptop as many have also suggested, still nothing.

What's interesting however is that I'm able to connect to the network folder just fine on another laptop that I have running Windows 10, so I'm pretty sure it's not an issue on the Ubuntu laptop side, but I know I screwed something up bad on the desktop side which is preventing the network folder from appearing again in any capacity. I've spent so much time searching as to what the issue could be but nothing seems to work.

If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is the firewall blocking the port?  Are you working as a local user or as an administrator or as an elevated administrator?  Some features need to be enabled as an elevated administrator before they will work.

Comment: I'm registered as an administrator on both Windows and Ubuntu, also I temporarily disabled all firewalls in Windows but still can't access the shared folder so I don't think that's the issue. Do you happen to know what features in particular I need to enable as an elevated administrator?

Comment: The suggestion to enable support for the deprecated SMB1.0 is wrong in so many levels. Ubuntu removed it long ago therefore you don't and shouldn't enable it on the client. It isn't needed because your network share is using a later version anyway.

Comment: Elevated administrator: open cmd prompt, on task bar, right click on cmd prompt, when the menu pops up, right click on cmd prompt - select **Run as administrator**.   Type in any passwords as required. The elevated cmd prompt will have **Administrator: Command Prompt** as its title.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *finally* got the network folder to appear. On Windows I opened the Registry Editor (Win key + R, then typing in `regedit`)

From there I navigated to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`, right-clicked (on the empty space to the right), selected `New` > `dword 32`, named it `AllowInsecureGuestAuth`

Double clicked on `AllowInsecureGuestAuth`, entered 1 into the `Value data` and hit OK.

Then I entered the IP address of my Ubuntu machine into the file explorer address bar in Windows, and there it was, fully accessible with no errors.